# WSO2 Create new API REST API throws 500 error

Tags: wso2, postman

I have been trying to create a new API in WSO2 using WSO2 REST services, While I am able to register DCR application, get authtoken and list down already existing APIs, the create new API call fails with 500 Error.
The same error I receive when trying to crate new API from WSO2 UI. Been using minimal required fields as well as tried with full API body given in documentation.

Here is the API Call:

```
Endpoint: **https://serverIP:9443/api/am/publisher/v1.2/apis**
Type : POST
Auth: Access-token
Body: {
  "name": "Rest Test API",
  "context": "/test",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}

Postman Response: {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal server error",
    "description": "The server encountered an internal error. Please contact administrator.",
    "moreInfo": "",
    "error": []
}
```

Tried checking the logs but they all point to no specific details except the null pointer exception.

> **Logs for reference:** https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-19] ERROR GlobalThrowableMapper An unknown exception has been captured by the
> global exception mapper. java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.validateSharedScopes_aroundBody486(APIProviderImpl.java:8708)
> ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.validateSharedScopes(APIProviderImpl.java:8706)
> ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.validateSharedScopes(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:1)
> ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.validateScopes(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:4510) ~[classes/:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.apisPost(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:278)
> ~[classes/:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.ApisApi.apisPost(ApisApi.java:962)
> ~[classes/:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
> ~[cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
> at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
> ~[cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]

What could be the problem? Is there a specific location I can see for specific logs?
TIA

Comment: the error returned by the server…the issue is with the API and not Postman.check any key or object u have set becomes null

Comment: What is the API Manager version you are using? You Publisher REST API version seems to be 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

According to the log, It seems like the payload you passed is invalid or missing mandatory fields.

Seems like, You have try to add a shared scope to an API which is not already defined. So please proceed and check the payload provided is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 points you need to consider in this case. They are as follows.

**1. Rest API version**

Based on your API endpoint "https://serverIP:9443/api/am/publisher/**v1.2**/apis" you are using the REST API version v1.2. Currently, WSO2 APIM does not support such a version. The latest wso2am-3.2.0 uses **v1** version. If you are using **wso2am-2.2.0** then the version should be **v0.12**. Please check this.

**2. Scopes**

In order to add new APIs via a REST API call, you should have generated the access tokens with the following OAuth 2.0 scope in order to access those resources. Please check if you have generated the access tokens with the relevant scopes.

- **wso2am-3.2.0:** apim:api_create ([link](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/product-apis/publisher-apis/publisher-v1/publisher-v1/#tag/APIs/paths/%7E1apis/post))
- **wso2am-2.2.0:** apim:api_create ([link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/apidocs/publisher/#!/operations#APIIndividual#apisPost))